# How to run an arbitrary script or executable from memory?

Tags: c, executable

I know I can use a system call like `execl("/bin/sh", "-c", some_string, 0)` to interpret a "snippet" of shell code using a particular shell/interpreter. But in my case I have an arbitrary string in memory that represents some complete script which needs to be run. That is, the contents of this string/memory buffer could be:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Hello"
```

Or they might be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

print "Hello from Python"
```

I suppose in theory the string/buffer could even include a valid binary executable, though that's not a particular priority.

My question is: is there any way to have the system launch a subprocess directly from a buffer of memory I give it, without writing it to a temporary file? Or at least, a way to give the string to a shell and have it route it to the proper interpreter?

It seems that all the system calls I've found expect a *path* to an existing executable, rather than something low level which takes an executable itself. I do **not** want to parse the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) or anything myself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178236/discussion-on-question-by-natevw-how-to-run-an-arbitrary-script-or-executable-fr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: is there any way to have the system launch a
>   subprocess directly from a buffer of memory I give it, without writing
>   it to a temporary file? Or at least, a way to give the string to a
>   shell and have it route it to the proper interpreter?
>
> It seems that all the system calls I've found expect a path to an
>   existing executable, rather than something low level which takes an
>   executable itself. I do not want to parse the shebang or anything
>   myself.

Simple answer: no.

Detailed answer:

`execl` and shebang convention are POSIXisms, so this answer will focus on POSIX systems.  Whether the program you want to execute is a script utilizing the shebang convention or a binary executable, [the `exec`-family functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) are *the* way for a userspace program to cause a different program to run.  Other interfaces such as `system()` and `popen()` are implemented on top of these.

The exec-family functions all expect to load a process image *from a file*.  Moreover, on success they replace the contents of the process in which they are called, including all memory assigned to it, with the new image.

More generally, substantially all modern operating systems enforce process isolation, and one of the central pillars of process isolation is that no process can access another's memory.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the operating system, but since `#!` is specific to Unix, I assume that's what you're talking about.

As far as I know, there's no system call that will load a program from a block of memory rather than a file. The lowest-level system call for loading a program is the `execve()` function, and it requires a pathname of the file to load from.